# How can we manually change some TF slim weights and use them to re-train, fine-tune, or predict

Tags: tensorflow

I am interested in changing some weights values in certain conv layers of a `tf-slim` model. Say `Mobilenet_v1`. Is there any straightforward way to do that while keeping the whole architecture and the data the same as before?

E.g.: 
Suppose we have got this numpy array of weights from the last level layer of trained MobileNet_v1:

```
>>> conv=sess.run('MobilenetV1/Conv2d_13_depthwise/depthwise_weights_2:0')
```

which gives me the whole array:

```
...


[ -7.38371849e-01],
[  1.39969051e+00],
[  1.34190738e+00],
[ -5.66634417e-01],
[ -2.53899932e-01],
[  1.18222773e-01],
[  2.57152438e-01],
[  2.43642002e-01],
[ -5.11337161e-01],
[ -5.80285192e-01],
[  3.62841874e-01],
[ -4.72957313e-01],
[  7.34595060e-01],
[ -7.35578299e-01],
[  6.73987687e-01]]]], dtype=float32)
```

for instance, I would like to search for all values within a specific range:

```
>>> numpy.count_nonzero((conv>=XX) & (conv<=YY))
```

and then set those values to zero. That means that I overwrite the new variables values, so then I use the new pre-trained model for further training, or, fine-tuning, or inference. How can I do that?

Comment: Could you give some context? As the weights are just variables, it should be straightforward to change them. `tf-slim` may not give you the toolkit, so you may need the lower-level TensorFlow functions (you will need to define an operation to do so and run it in a session, but otherwise no different from changing some values in a NumPy array as far as I can tell). It's a bit unusual to want to manually change weights - as opposed to just train on more data - so perhaps explain your goal there.

Comment: @NeilSlater. OK. Please have a look at my updated question.

Comment: What you want to do is very likely possible in TensorFlow, but not how fine-tuning is usually done. It may not work very well. What is the driver for you doing this? It is fine if you just want to try it and see what happens, I am just concerned that you might have an X/Y problem, so if someone puts the correct answer you will try it then ask "why is my network performing badly after I do this" because you have some expectation that setting weights like this will improve the network (I don't know for certain, but I think it probably won't).

Comment: I see @NeilSlater . So I was hoping I could be able to test this to see the changes (negative or positive). Do you think you can provide a sample MWE so I start with?